# phonegap multiple media players

Tags: cordova

I'm trying to convert a program another person wrote for the xcode version phonegap for android. The program has background music with sounds triggered on the pages. Here's the DeviceReady function he wrote:

```
function phonegapReady() {
console.log('PHONEGAP READY');
gPhoneGap = true;

gMusicPlayer1 = new Media("/android_asset/www/sound/T1_music.mp3", onSuccess, onError);

gMusicPlayer1.play({numberOfLoops: 9999});

gMusicPlayer2 = new Media("/android_asset/www/sound/T1.mp3", onSuccess, onError);

gMusicPlayer2.play();
setVolume(gMusicPlayer2, 0, 0);
gMusicPlayer2.stop();


console.log('PHONEGAP READY DONE');
```

}

However it seems like only the 2nd player plays a sound and the the 1st doesnt start up. Is it possible to create seperate media objects this way?